# How to add formula field on dashboard filter?

Tags: apex, dashboard, custom-report-type

I have created a summary report and added that report to the dashboard.
When i am trying to add a filter on dashboard i am getting formula field of opportunity in filter option. And also not getting any text filed in dashboard filter.

Comment: you should use [edit] and amend you question with more details including screen shot and the specific fields you are seeing/not seeing and their types

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce currently [doesn't support formula field in dashboard filter](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dashboard_filters_overview.htm&language=en_US&type=0):

> There are some things you can’t do with dashboard filters.
>
> - Filters can’t be added to dashboards that contain Visualforce or s-control components.
> - It’s not possible to filter on bucket fields. However, it is possible to use a report filtered on a bucket field on the dashboard page.
> - Filters aren’t applied when you schedule or email a dashboard.
> - You can’t filter data on a joined report in dashboard view or add a filter to a dashboard that only has joined reports.
> - **You can’t use custom formula fields in a dashboard filter.**
> - In Lightning Experience, you can’t edit filtered dashboards, which means you can’t add new dashboard filters. (You can change existing filters while viewing the dashboard, though!) Switch to Salesforce Classic to edit filtered dashboards.

Comment: Salesforce supports [dashboard filters](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dashboard_filters_overview.htm&language=en_US&type=0). The question was why few fields were not available in the filter.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce can add formula field on Dashboard Filter.

How :

1) Make sure Field Level Security of that formula field is visible to all intended parties

2) Make sure to add the formula field to the specific **custom report type** of the report you are adding to Dashboard